# Override an image from a bundle

Tags: symfony

I have this:

```
ShopBundle
  Controller
  Resources
    public
      images
        marker.png
    views
      Default
        index.html.twig
```

In my index.html.twig, I'd like to have this

```
<img src="{{ asset("images/marker.png") }}"/>
```

And I'd love people using my bundle who just want to use their own marker.png to just have to build a bundle inheriting mine and place their image just by following files structure:

```
MyShopBundle
  Resources
    public
      images
        marker.png
```

Is there any simple way to do this in Symfony2 ? The need seems so simple that I can't believe I didn't find answers already.

So,

- How do you include an image asset in your bundle template from your bundle resources directory ? I already did a `./apps/hfr/console assets:install web` but my template does not print the right url (/images/marker.png instead of /bundles/ShopBundle/Resources/public/images/png)
- Is it possible to override the way I want or did I lost my way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

use the @ syntax ...

```
{% image '@VendorMyShopBundleBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg'
    output='/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example"/>
{% endimage %}
```

Please note that **Vendor/YourBundle/Resources/public** will NOT be accessible by your web server normally.

The assets:install command will therefore copy the assets to **web/bundles/vendoryourbundle**

The {{ asset('path/to/asset.jpg') }} function will adjust the url of your asset if youre using the dev environment:

```
 http://hostname/app_dev.php
```

from

```
/path/to/asset.jpg
```

to

```
/app_dev.php/to/asset.jpg
```

[EDIT]

if you want more control over the assets maybe consider using **asset collections**.

You can configure them as follows:

```
# app/Resources/config/config.yml

assetic:
    [...]
    assets:
        css_bootstrap:
            inputs:
                -  %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Vendor/YourBundle/Resources/public/twitter-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
                - [...]
            filters:
                - lessphp
                - [...]
            output: css/bootstrap.css

         my_image:
            inputs: 
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../path/to/image.png
            filters:
                - optipng
            output: images/image-with-new-name.png
```

and use them afterwards in your template like this:

```
{% stylesheets '@css_bootstrap' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I am NOT sure right now if the assetic/assets/packagename/inputs configuration array supports the @VendorYourBundle syntax aswell and then uses bundle inheritance though.

**Addition:**

Before you can use these packages you will have to use the console command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```