# symfony js file URLs without assets/compile for development

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1

I'm working on a symfony2 project and all the js and css files are served from the compiled version under /assets/compiled/frontend_site_2.css  /assets/compiled/frontend_jscript_2.js and the actual version of these files are under

src\projectname\Bundle\WebBundle\Resources\assets\js\jscript.js
src\projectname\Bundle\WebBundle\Resources\assets\css\site.js

I want the view to render these urls instead of compiled versions, right now I 've to dump these files by running this cmd php app/console assetic:dump --watch
I don't want to run this command after every single modication, is it possible?

```
frontend/javascript_block.htm.twig file
{% javascripts output='assets/compiled/frontend.js'
    '@projectNameWebBundle/Resources/public/js/jscript.js'
%}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please refer this 
1) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749407/load-one-js-file-using-assetic-inside-symfony2

Comment: `assets:install web --symlink` don't solve your problem?

Comment: @Isouza, no nothing works, I've tried many things but its still serving the files from /assets/compiled/frontend_jscript_2.js, now every time I do modification to refresh this compiled version I run this cmd app/console assetic:dump. I'm tired of this.

Answer (score 0):

In dev mode you can just put list of js files you want to include in 'javascripts' block, like this:

```
{% javascripts
'@YourBundle/Resources/public/path/to/your_js_file'
'@YourBundle/Resources/public/path/to/your_another_js_file'
 %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

So, it looks like your sample except this strange place: "output=". I haven't met anything like this before.

To work with javascript files without constantly run dump command you can use sample above. It works on several my projects. And I think it must work for you.

In production mode just run

```
assetic:dump
```

command and that's it.